# Count calls and update table accordingly

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

This is literally the first time I've ever used JavaScript so I know it's really bad and how to improve it just not how to implement it. Basically, I need to loop through all the elements instead of manually checking and updating each one. Any suggestions on how to do that, and other recommendations?

```html
<!-- Kalenpw -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1{
                font-size: 2.5em;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

            }

            table {
                border: 5px ridge black;
                width:99%;
                margin-left: .1%;

                background-color: #bdbdbd;
            }

            #btnNextCall{
                margin-left: .1%;
                width: 99%;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: #58acfa;
                border: 2px solid #58acfa;
                color: white;
                font-size: 2em;
                font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
                transition-duration: .3s;

            }

            #btnNextCall:hover{
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                cursor: pointer;


            }

            th{
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 1.6em;
                background-color: #58acfa;
                color: white;
                text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
                font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
            }

            td:first-child{
                text-align: left;
            }

            td{
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
                background-color: #cdcdcd;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) td{
                background-color: #e6e6e6;
            }

            input[type="checkbox"]{
                width:20px;
                height:20px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .categoryHeader{
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                font-size: 1.4em;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            tr{
                display: table-row;
            }

            .hide-me
            {
                display: none;
            }

        </style>
        <script>
//Global variables
            var totalCalls = 0;
            var totalBoxOne = 0;
            var totalBoxTwo = 0;
            var totalBoxThree = 0;
            var totalBoxFour = 0;
            var totalBoxFive = 0;
            var totalBoxSix = 0;
            var totalBoxSeven = 0;
            var totalBoxEight = 0;
            var totalBoxNine = 0;
            var totalBoxTen = 0;
            var totalBox11 = 0;
            var totalBox12 = 0;
            var totalBox13 = 0;
            var totalBox14 = 0;
            var totalBox15 = 0;
            var totalBox16 = 0;
            var totalBox17 = 0;
            var totalBox18 = 0;
            var totalBox19 = 0;
            var totalBox20 = 0;
            var totalBox21 = 0;
            var totalBox22 = 0;
            var totalBox23 = 0;
            var totalBox24 = 0;
            var totalBox25 = 0;


            function collapseCatOne() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catOne");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatTwo() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catTwo");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatThree() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catThree");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatFour() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catFour");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatFive() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catFive");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatSix() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catSix");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function collapseCatSeven() {
                var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("catSeven");

                for (var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
                    collapse[i].classList.toggle("hide-me");
                }
            }

            function nextCall() {

                //totals boxes
                totalCalls = totalCalls + 1;
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxOne").checked) {
                    totalBoxOne = totalBoxOne + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxTwo").checked) {
                    totalBoxTwo = totalBoxTwo + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxThree").checked) {
                    totalBoxThree = totalBoxThree + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxFour").checked) {
                    totalBoxFour = totalBoxFour + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxFive").checked) {
                    totalBoxFive = totalBoxFive + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxSix").checked) {
                    totalBoxSix = totalBoxSix + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxSeven").checked) {
                    totalBoxSeven = totalBoxSeven + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxEight").checked) {
                    totalBoxEight = totalBoxEight + 1;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxNine").checked) {
                    totalBoxNine++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBoxTen").checked) {
                    totalBoxTen++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox11").checked) {
                    totalBox11++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox12").checked) {
                    totalBox12++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox13").checked) {
                    totalBox13++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox14").checked) {
                    totalBox14++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox15").checked) {
                    totalBox15++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox16").checked) {
                    totalBox16++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox17").checked) {
                    totalBox17++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox18").checked) {
                    totalBox18++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox19").checked) {
                    totalBox19++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox20").checked) {
                    totalBox20++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox21").checked) {
                    totalBox21++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox22").checked) {
                    totalBox22++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox23").checked) {
                    totalBox23++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox24").checked) {
                    totalBox24++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("checkBox25").checked) {
                    totalBox25++;
                }


                //Display ratio
                document.getElementById("rowOneTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxOne + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowTwoTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxTwo + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowThreeTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxThree + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowFourTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxFour + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowFiveTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxFive + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowSixTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxSix + "/" + totalCalls;

                document.getElementById("rowSevenTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxSeven + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowEightTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxEight + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowNineTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxNine + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("rowTenTotal").innerHTML = totalBoxTen + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row11Total").innerHTML = totalBox11 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row12Total").innerHTML = totalBox12 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row13Total").innerHTML = totalBox13 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row14Total").innerHTML = totalBox14 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row15Total").innerHTML = totalBox15 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row16Total").innerHTML = totalBox16 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row17Total").innerHTML = totalBox17 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row18Total").innerHTML = totalBox18 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row19Total").innerHTML = totalBox19 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row20Total").innerHTML = totalBox20 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row21Total").innerHTML = totalBox21 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row22Total").innerHTML = totalBox22 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row23Total").innerHTML = totalBox23 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row24Total").innerHTML = totalBox24 + "/" + totalCalls;
                document.getElementById("row25Total").innerHTML = totalBox25 + "/" + totalCalls;




                //Display percent
                document.getElementById("rowOnePercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxOne / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowTwoPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxTwo / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowThreePercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxThree / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowFourPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxFour / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowFivePercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxFive / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowSixPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxSix / totalCalls * 100) + "%";

                document.getElementById("rowSevenPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxSeven / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowEightPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxEight / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowNinePercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxNine / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("rowTenPercent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBoxTen / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row11Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox11 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row12Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox12 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row13Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox13 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row14Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox14 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row15Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox15 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row16Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox16 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row17Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox17 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row18Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox18 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row19Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox19 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row20Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox20 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row21Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox21 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row22Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox22 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row23Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox23 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row24Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox24 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";
                document.getElementById("row25Percent").innerHTML = Math.round(totalBox25 / totalCalls * 100) + "%";


                //Uncheck boxes
                document.getElementById("checkBoxOne").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxTwo").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxThree").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxFour").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxFive").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxSix").checked = false;

                document.getElementById("checkBoxSeven").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxEight").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxNine").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBoxTen").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox11").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox12").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox13").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox14").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox15").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox16").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox17").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox18").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox19").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox20").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox21").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox22").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox23").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox24").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("checkBox25").checked = false;


            }

        </script>

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">-->
        <title>Tracker</title>
        <!--<script src="javascript.js"></script>-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Tracker</h1>

        <table>
            <!--Header-->
            <tr>
                <th>Metric</th>
                <th>This call</th>
                <th>Overall</th>
                <th>Percent</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Conversation<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatOne()">Collapse</button> </td>                            
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Greet</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxOne" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowOneTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowOnePercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Identify & Verify</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxTwo" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowTwoTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowTwoPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Engagement</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxThree" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowThreeTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowThreePercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Empathy</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxFour" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowFourTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowFourPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Courtesy</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxFive" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowFiveTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowFivePercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catOne">
                <td>Acknowledge History</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxSix" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowSixTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowSixPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Accountability<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatTwo()">Collapse</button></td>                            
            </tr>

            <!--Category two-->
            <tr class="catTwo">
                <td>Customer Pace</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxSeven" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowSevenTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowSevenPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catTwo">
                <td>Pause & Clarify</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxEight" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowEightTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowEightPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <!--Category three-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Root Cause Probing<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatThree()">Collapse</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catThree">
                <td>Root Cause</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxNine" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowNineTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowNinePercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catThree">
                <td>Uncover WINs</td>
                <td><input id="checkBoxTen" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="rowTenTotal">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="rowTenPercent">%</div></td>
            </tr>     

            <!--Category four-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Extend Choices<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatFour()">Collapse</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catFour">
                <td>Present Appropriate Solution</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox11" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row11Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row11Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catFour">
                <td>Tie FABs to WINs</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox12" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row12Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row12Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>  

            <tr class="catFour">
                <td>Handle Objections</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox13" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row13Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row13Percent">%</div></td>

            </tr>

            <!--Category five-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Solve the Real Root Cause<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatFive()">Collapse</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catFive">
                <td>Use Tools</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox14" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row14Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row14Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catFive">
                <td>Check Back with Customer</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox15" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row15Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row15Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>  

            <!--Category six-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">End Call on a Positive Note<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatSix()">Collapse</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSix">
                <td>Think Future/Execution</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox16" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row16Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row16Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSix">
                <td>Promote</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox17" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row17Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row17Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>  

            <tr class="catSix">
                <td>Closing Statement</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox18" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row18Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row18Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <!--Category seven-->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="categoryHeader">Extras<button type="button" onclick="collapseCatSeven()">Collapse</button></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox19" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row19Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row19Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Credit</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox20" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row20Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row20Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>  

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Transfers</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox21" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row21Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row21Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Claims</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox22" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row22Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row22Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Punch in Rate</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox23" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row23Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row23Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>  

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Call Intent POPs</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox24" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row24Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row24Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="catSeven">
                <td>Proactive POPs</td>
                <td><input id="checkBox25" type="checkbox" name="metricDone" value="check"></td>
                <td><div id="row25Total">/</div></td>
                <td><div id="row25Percent">%</div></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <button id="btnNextCall" type="button" onclick="nextCall()">Next Call</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem using raw JavaScript, it would help to eliminate all of your `totalBoxN` variables, as well as the `catN` classes and `rowNTotal` and `checkBoxN` IDs.  The trick is to store the counts directly in the DOM using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).  That way, you avoid having to build a JavaScript data structure to mirror the contents of the HTML table.

Compared to a jQuery solution, a raw JavaScript solution spends a lot more effort doing simple tasks like toggling the presence of a class attribute and replacing the content of a table cell.  It's not really easier to learn raw JavaScript than jQuery, especially when you take into account that jQuery solves many browser compatibility issues that you wouldn't even know about unless you had a lot of experience or testing.

In addition to my previous remarks, I suggest avoiding free-floating code at the top level.  Instead, you should package code inside functions, and declare `'use strict;'` to help catch any silly typos.

It is also considered cleaner to have your JavaScript code attach its own event handlers to the DOM, rather than embedding `onclick` attributes in the HTML.

### Suggested solution (without jQuery)

```js
function tracker(table, button) {
    'use strict';
    var callCount = 0;

    // Handler for collapse / expand
    var buttons = table.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
        buttons[b].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var section = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
            var classes = (section.className || '').split(/\s+/);
            var collapse = classes.indexOf('collapse');
            if (collapse >= 0) {
                classes.splice(collapse, 1);  // Remove it
            } else {
                classes.push('collapse');
            }
            section.className = classes.join(' ');
        });
    }

    // Handler for "Next Call" button
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        ++callCount;

        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
            var inputs = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('input');
            if (!inputs.length) {
                continue; // Ignore section header
            }
            var rowCount = parseInt(inputs[0].getAttribute('data-count') || '0');
            if (inputs[0].checked) {
                inputs[0].setAttribute('data-count', ++rowCount);
                inputs[0].checked = false;
            }
            fill(rows[r], 'overall', '' + rowCount + '/' + callCount);
            fill(rows[r], 'percent', '' + Math.round(100 * rowCount / callCount) + '%');
        }
    });

    // Helper to replace the content of a table cell with matching header
    function fill(row, cellHeader, text) {
        for (var c = 0; c < row.childNodes.length; c++) {
            var headers = (row.childNodes[c].getAttribute('headers') || '').split(/\s+/);
            if (headers.indexOf(cellHeader) >= 0) {
                row.childNodes[c].textContent = text;
            }
        }
    }
}


tracker(document.getElementById('tracker'),
        document.getElementById('btnNextCall'));
```

```css
table.tracker caption {
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.tracker {
    border: 5px ridge black;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: .1%;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

table.tracker > thead th {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #58acfa;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

table.tracker th,
table.tracker td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr > th {
    text-align: left;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table.tracker > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

table.tracker > tbody.collapse > tr:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}

button.tracker {
    margin-left: .1%;
    width: 99%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #58acfa;
    border: 2px solid #58acfa;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

button.tracker:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">-->
        <title>Tracker</title>
        <!--<script src="javascript.js"></script>-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="tracker" id="tracker">
            <caption>Tracker</caption>
            <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th id="metric">Metric</th>
                    <th id="this-call">This call</th>
                    <th id="overall">Overall</th>
                    <th id="percent">Percent</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Conversation<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Greet</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Identify &amp; Verify</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Engagement</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Empathy</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Courtesy</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Acknowledge History</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Accountability<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Customer Pace</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Pause &amp; Clarify</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Root Cause Probing<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Root Cause</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Uncover WINs</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Extend Choices<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Present Appropriate solution</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Tie FABs to WINs</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Handle Objections</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Solve the Real Root Cause<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Use Tools</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Check Back with Customer</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">End Call on a Positive Note<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Think Future/Execution</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Promote</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Closing Statement</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th colspan="4">Extras<button>Collapse</button></th></tr>
                <tr><th>Email</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Credit</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Transfers</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Claims</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Punch in Rate</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Call Intent POPs</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Proactive POPs</th><td headers="this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td><td headers="overall">/</td><td headers="percent">%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="btnNextCall" class="tracker">Next Call</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many commendable aspects of your mini application:

- The HTML is beautifully laid out.
- You've used the HTML5 doctype, and the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` declaration.
- The CSS is readable, and the subtle animation effects are a nice touch.

And most of all, if this is truly the first time you've used JavaScript, and you managed to get this working, I'm impressed!

Unfortunately, the HTML and the JavaScript are both heavily repetitive.  In my opinion, this approach will end up being a maintenance headache, if you ever need to add items to or remove items from the rubric.

Furthermore, this problem is something I wouldn't even think of tackling using raw JavaScript.  You would need some kind of abstraction layer.  In my opinion, jQuery is almost essential.

For those reasons, I recommend starting with a fresh approach.  (I don't mean to discourage you, but I think you'll see the advantage once you compare the code.)

### General principles

If you have many of the same kind of variable, don't use multiple variables.  Use an array instead.

Find a way to use the same click handler for multiple user interface elements.  For example, you should only need to write one `collapseCat()` function; the function can decide which category to collapse by examining the source of the click event.

Keeping the HTML and JavaScript code consistent with each other is a pain.  Ideally, you want to define the rubric just once.  You could either have the JavaScript scrape the HTML, or have the JavaScript generate the HTML.  Since the HTML table is verbose and repetitive, I'd rather define a JavaScript data structure and generate the HTML from it.

[HTML tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html) have some markup features you could take advantage of:

- Label each `<td>` with a [`headers`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43.html) attribute, to make it easy to find out which row and column it is associated with.
- Use a `<thead>` to mark the first row.
- Use a separate `<tbody>` for each category.  (This messes up the strict zebra stripe alternation.  With the proper header styling, I don't think that's a bad thing.)
- Optionally use a `<caption>` instead of `<h1>`.

### Suggested solution

```js
function tracker($table, $button, rubric) {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the metrics in each category to 0
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/1295584
    var metricCounts = rubric.map(function(category) {
        for (var categoryName in category) {
            return new Array(category[categoryName].length).fill(0);
        }
    });
    var callCount = 0;

    // Create the HTML table body
    for (var c = 0; c < rubric.length; c++) {
        var category = rubric[c];
        for (var categoryName in category) {
            var $cat = $('<tbody></tbody>')
                .append($('<tr></tr>')
                    .append($('<th colspan="4"></th></tr>')
                        .text(categoryName)
                        .append('<button>Collapse</button>')
                    )
                );
            $table.append($cat);

            var metrics = category[categoryName];
            for (var m = 0; m < metrics.length; m++) {
                var metricId = 'metric' + c + '.' + m;
                var $row = $('<tr></tr>')
                    .append($('<th id="' + metricId +'"></th>').text(metrics[m]))
                    .append('<td headers="' + metricId + ' this-call"><input type="checkbox"></td>')
                    .append('<td headers="' + metricId + ' overall">/</td>')
                    .append('<td headers="' + metricId + ' percent">%</td>');
                $cat.append($row);
            }
        }
    }

    // Handler for collapse / expand
    $table.on('click', 'button', function toggleCollapse() {
        $(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('collapse');
    });

    // Handler for "Next Call" button
    $button.on('click', function nextCall() {
        // Update metrics and clear the checkboxes
        ++callCount;
        $table.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            var headers = $(this).closest('td').attr('headers');
            var match = /metric(\d+)\.(\d+)/.exec(headers);
            ++metricCounts[match[1]][match[2]];
        }).prop('checked', false);

        // Display new statistics
        for (var c = 0; c < metricCounts.length; c++) {
            for (var m = 0; m < metricCounts[c].length; m++) {
                var metricId = 'metric' + c + '.' + m;
                $('td[headers="' + metricId + ' overall"]').text('' + metricCounts[c][m] + '/' + callCount);
                $('td[headers="' + metricId + ' percent"]').text('' + Math.round(100 * metricCounts[c][m] / callCount) + '%');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    tracker($('#tracker'), $('#btnNextCall'), [
        {
            'Conversation': [
                'Greet',
                'Identify & Verify',
                'Engagement',
                'Empathy',
                'Courtesy',
                'Acknowledge History',
            ],
        }, {
            'Accountability': [
                'Customer Pace',
                'Pause & Clarify',
            ]
        }, {
            'Root Cause Probing': [
                'Root Cause',
                'Uncover WINs',
            ]
        }, {
            'Extend Choices': [
                'Present Appropriate solution',
                'Tie FABs to WINs',
                'Handle Objections',
            ]
        }, {
            'Solve the Real Root Cause': [
                'Use Tools',
                'Check Back with Customer',
            ]
        }, {
            'End Call on a Positive Note': [
                'Think Future/Execution',
                'Promote',
                'Closing Statement',
            ]
        }, {
            'Extras': [
                'Email',
                'Credit',
                'Transfers',
                'Claims',
                'Punch in Rate',
                'Call Intent POPs',
                'Proactive POPs',
            ]
        },
    ]);
});
```

```css
table.tracker caption {
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.tracker {
    border: 5px ridge black;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: .1%;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

table.tracker > thead th {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #58acfa;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

table.tracker th,
table.tracker td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr > th {
    text-align: left;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
table.tracker > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table.tracker > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

table.tracker > tbody.collapse > tr:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}

button.tracker {
    margin-left: .1%;
    width: 99%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #58acfa;
    border: 2px solid #58acfa;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

button.tracker:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">-->
        <title>Tracker</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="javascript.js"></script>-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table class="tracker" id="tracker">
            <caption>Tracker</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="metric">Metric</th>
                    <th id="this-call">This call</th>
                    <th id="overall">Overall</th>
                    <th id="percent">Percent</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <button class="tracker" id="btnNextCall">Next Call</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate that. I intentionally didn't use jquery because I figured it would be better to learn vanilla js first